# context data not getting displayed in inherited template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

**Base HTML**

```
    {% load static %}
             {% include "navigation/navigation.html" with cat=categories only %}
  <!-- base template  -->
           
            {% block content %}
                  some html
        
            
            
            {% endblock%}
```

**Template B**

```
{% extends "base/index.html" %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
        <!-- product right -->
         Some html
        <!-- //product right -->
    
    
    <!-- //product right -->
    {% endblock %}
```

My issue is when I am rendering template b its not showing the context I have passed to the navigation bar, even though when accessing the base template alone context is getting displayed fine, don't know where is the issue,

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do this

```
{% extends "base/index.html" %}
```

just do this

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
```

remove base/index.html

Comment: but my index.html is in base folder which is in templates directory as you can guess

Comment: i know, i do this my self every time, i have template folder in root directory and i have base.html and index.html in it, then i use {% extends 'base.html'%} in my second, or any other html files